# How to test this sortingBean using FacesContext

Tags: junit, mocking, facescontext

I wrote myself a`SortingBean`which is similiar to the`CarsSortingBean`over [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=edt-sorting&skin=blueSky). I want to write a unit test for this class but I don't know how to do this. I got problems with the first line of the `sort` method. How can I successfully mock this?

I already found out, that there is something called`MockFacesContext`:

```
@Test
public void testSort() throws Exception {
    facesContextMock = MockFacesContext.getMockContext(true);
    replay(facesContextMock);

    classUnderTest.sort();
}
```

With this test I am getting a`NullPointerException`because the`RequestParameterMap`is not filled.

Can you give me any hint of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say move sorting logic to other class that does not know about JSF context.
Then, for example, create method `setSortParameter(String)` and fill it in unit test and in this bean.

I've had hard time playing with mock JSF contexts for a few years (using Shale framework + JSF 1.1) and I'm not going to do it any more.